# Toggling classes using Angular 2 Services

Tags: angular

I am trying to create an example where classes can be added/removed using angular 2 services. Here is a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/qLzgTca6Ul4W6OpBXG7w?p=preview

What I am basically doing is on the click of a button, I am trying to toggle a class across different selectors spread across the application using a service:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable()
export class AppService{
    background: boolean = false; //Scrolling is on by default
}
```

The background flag decides if the background should change or not:

ComponentA:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppService} from './app.service';

@Component({
    selector: "comp-a",
    template: `
      <div>
        Component A!
        <button (click)="onClick()">Click me</button>
      </div>
    `
})
export class ComponentA{

  constructor(private _appService: AppService){

  }

  onClick(){
    this._appService.background = true;
    console.log(this._appService.background);
  }
}
```

Directive C:

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppService} from './app.service';

@Directive({
    selector: "my-app",
    host: {'[class.backgroundBlue]':'_appService.background'}
})
export class DirectiveC{

  constructor(private _appService: AppService){

  }
}
```

App:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {ComponentA} from './a.component';
import {ComponentB} from './b.component';
import {DirectiveC} from './c.directive';

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
      <div>
        App Component!
        <comp-a></comp-a>
        <comp-b></comp-b>
      </div>
    `,
    directives: [ComponentA,ComponentB,DirectiveC]
})
export class AppComponent{
}
```

When I click on the button in ComponentA the color of the ComponentB changes but why doesn't it affect the selector for DirectiveC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `DirectiveC` into the list of directives of the `AppComponent`:

```
directives: [ComponentA, ComponentB, DirectiveC]
```

So the directive isn't applied.

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/JwskUymdNgGTRtnzuD4s?p=preview.

Comment: I think the problem here is that AppComponent is you main component, i.e. the component you bootstrap...

Comment: even if i replace the selector of DirectiveC with the body tag it doesn't work.

Comment: In fact the class is added to the element. For example: `comp-a`. Something like that: `<comp-a class="backgroundBlue">...`